# How to open google Navigate api in flutter web

Tags: flutter

I tried to launch Google Maps with google navigate API inside my Flutter web using the URL Launcher package the map is loading but I got an error Google Maps can't open this link

google.navigation:q=${25.1972}, ${55.2744}
this is the url i used to launch google navigation

This is url working fine on mobile
i already added the key details in index.html Also
if anyone knows how to launch this navigation in Flutter Web
google navigate api in Flutter Web